# Remove duplicated record in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

What I'm trying to do is take records that looks like this:

```
ID  NAME    STARTDATE   ENDDATE EnrollmentMonth
1   PETER   20190101    20200729    20200701    
1   TONY    20200730    99991231    20200701
```

and change it to look like this:

```
ID  NAME    STARTDATE   ENDDATE EnrollmentMonth
1   PETER   20190101    20200729    20200701
```

Excluding the name that has less enrollment days, Peter enrolled for 29 days in July while Tony enrolled for 2 days in July.

The idea is to pick only one name in July.

I am having difficult time making this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this per user ID? For every month or just the enrollment month?  What have you tried? What was your result?

Comment: I'm feeling really dumb. How is it, with this data, that Tony enrolled for 2 days? I don't get the math at all here.

Comment: the enrollment in July.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just one record for July, which has the lest number of enrolment days, you can use date arithmetics, `order by` and `fetch first`:

```
select *
from mytable
where enrollmentmonth = date '2020-07-01'
order by least(enddate, date '2020-07-31') - greatest(startdate, '2020-07-01')
fetch first row with ties
```

We can implement the same logic on a per-month basis using window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        rank() over(
            partition by enrollmentmonth 
            order by least(enddate, last_day(enrollmentmonth)) - greatest(startdate, trunc(enrollmentmonth, 'month'))
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Should that be `date '2020-07-01'`?